# Python Xlsxwriter formating specific column in a table

Tags: python, format, xlsxwriter

In my python code I am creating a table using xlsxwriter and would like to know if there is a way to format one of the columns to be of type 'accounting'. I already have the format saved for my other cells:

```
num_field = workbook.add_format(
        {
            "num_format": 44
        }
    )
```

I know this is correct as it works for my other cells. However, when I add the table using my code below:

```
worksheet_budget.add_table('E2:G50', {'data': data,
                               'columns': [{'header': 'Item'},
                                           {'header': 'Category'},
                                           {'header': 'Cost', 'format': num_field},
                                           ]})
```

It does not format the 'cost' column to be of that format.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining the format as:

```
num_field = workbook.add_format(
    {
        "num_format": 44
    }
  )
```

Try

```
num_field = workbook.add_format(
 {
   "num_format":"_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* "-"??_);_(@_)"
 }
)
```

Sometimes the index number for the format doesn't work.

Comment: This did not work for me, it is still stuck in general formatting